# Bash script error: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm attempting to run this shell script but I get the errors:

> unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

and

> syntax error: unexpected end of file

There's no error when I switch .asd/‘ to .asd/' but nothing seems to happen.  The goal of the script is to tell me which music files in /Music don't have a corresponding .asd file.  Script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=`mdfind -onlyin ~/Music “kMDItemUserTags==Green” | sed -E -e 's/\.[a-zA-Z1-3]+$/.asd/‘`
for aFile in $files 
do
    if [ ! -e $aFile ]; then
        echo $aFile;
    fi
done
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Whatever editor it is you write scripts with, get rid of it. This looks like a MS-Word text file was saved as a script, with all the fancy UTF-8 curly quotes instead of ASCII plain quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've got curly quotes inside of the mdfind. The curly quotes aren't interpreted the same way straight quotes are. So while replacing the `‘` with `'` resolved the end of file error, you probably aren't matching anything with the `“kMDItemUserTags==Green”`. Try replacing it with `"kMDItemUserTags==Green"` and see if that works.

What's happening with the single quote is it's matching the first one and not the second, so when you get to the closing quote (curly), it keeps thinking that's part of the quoted string, and keeps reading until the end of the file (`EOF`).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ooops, that `n't` sure makes a different in context huh.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! No luck unfortunately - perhaps there's something wrong with the script (or maybe I misinterpreted - the script was written for me; I'm out of my realm of knowledge). Making both the double and the single quotes straight (and leaving the backticks alone) gives no result when I run the script.  Straightening the double quotes and leaving the single quotes as they were gives the same errors as before, but I was assuming I should not do that.

Comment: @Farinuts: "Straightening" the quotes is definitely necessary; if you don't get results after that, the implication is that your Spotlight query (`mdfind ...`) simply returns no results. I suggest you accept this answer, because it solves your original problem, and if you have a follow-up question about why your `mdfind` command doesn't work, ask a _new_ question.

Answer (score 5):

To complement [Alex Ives's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285408/45375):

The praises of [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) for syntax-checking shell scripts have been sung many times, and justifiably so:

If we paste your script there (after splitting the pipeline into 2 lines for readability), we get (additional, incidental messages omitted here, but listed further below):

```
Line 2:
files=`mdfind -onlyin ~/Music “kMDItemUserTags==Green” | 
                              ^-- SC1015: This is a unicode double quote. Delete and retype it.
                                                     ^-- SC1015: This is a unicode double quote. Delete and retype it.

Line 3:
  sed -E -e 's/\.[a-zA-Z1-3]+$/.asd/‘`
                                    ^-- SC1016: This is a unicode single quote. Delete and retype it.
```

As you can see, [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) would have identified your problem and additionally would have provided the following pointers:

```
Line 2:
files=`mdfind -onlyin ~/Music “kMDItemUserTags==Green” | 
      ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.

Line 6:
    if [ ! -e $aFile ]; then
              ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 7:
        echo $aFile;
             ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

---

Additionally, you shouldn't enumerate filenames with `for`, as that will break with filenames with embedded spaces, for instance.

Instead, use:

```
while IFS= read -r aFile; do
  # work with "$aFile"
done < <(mdfind -onlyin ~/Music ...)
```

<sup>[William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) correctly points out in a comment that `IFS= read -r aFile` fails with filenames with embedded *newlines*.

That said, filenames with embedded *newlines* are rarely a real-world concern; by contrast, filenames with embedded *spaces* are, which is the case that `IFS= read -r aFile` handles correctly.</sup>

Comment: `while IFS= read -r aFile` will fail on files with names that contain embedded newlines.  You can really only reliably split on a nul byte.  eg, `while read -d $'\0'`, but it's more sane to enforce a policy of not allowing whitespace in filenames.